# How to getDistributable() in Java Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-boot, cluster-computing

I  configured

> `<distributable/>`

in web.xml . Now I need to check if the web application is distributable or not.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this from the Tomcat [context](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Context.html#getDistributable()). You can define the embedded Tomcat container as a @Bean and get it from there.

```
import org.apache.catalina.Context;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    private static boolean distributable;

    public static boolean getDistributable() {
        return distributable;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatFactory() {

        return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                Application.distributable = context.getDistributable();
                System.out.println("distributable is :"+distributable);
            }
        };
    }   
}
```

You may need to [setDistributable](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Context.html#setDistributable(boolean))(true/false) programmaticly in the factory for this to work accurately.

Comment: How do i get context ?

Comment: Thanks but i have already done this one. I am looking for some runtime code.

Comment: public static String isDistributable;
isDistributable=false (inside tomcat customizer bean). And access anywhere with MyClass.isDistributable .Is this what you mean?

Comment: This gives me correct ans but how can i be sure if the application config is set to be distributable? Is there any way to check if my application is set to be distributable?This only ensures that i have set the Boolean value to the variable.

Comment: Actually i had set the context on Application.groovy. I am on Grails 3+(Spring boot application). The object that set the distributable to true of course gets the same value as true (context.setDistributable(true) and context.get(Distributable) ---> same object 'context').So I was thinking of getting the context value in a different way.

Comment: and yes tomcat instance has only method of addContext().